# Is it possible to change iPhone only app to universal?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Is it possible to change iPhone only app to universal? I've been taking over some work of an old co-worker, the app was officially only for iPhone but since iOS 11 is out, I had to update it. I have change everything to fit perfectly on an iPad, scaling, devices (iphone to universal) etc. I've uploaded the update to the app store but the app still didn't change from iphone only to ipad and iphone. Everything look good when I download the iphone version to the ipad but I can't find it when i search for the app in the ipad only section. I've been looking around the web but didn't find a clear solution. everything seem a bit outdated.
In the `info.plist` in the `Required device capabilities` I have a `Key:Item 0` `Value: armv7`
could this be my problem? I just want to make sure before I send out my app in revision and it doesn't update after 1-2 days of waiting time.

Comment: No, `armv7` is not your problem. It does not disciminate between iPhones or iPads. It might just take some time for the changes to roll out properly. How long ago did you publish it?

Comment: It as been over 24 hours. I'll wait until tomorrow to see, if not i'll contact apple. Thanks

Comment: Did you add screenshots for the iPad?